# C# Sending Excel xls over WebAPI controller to js and save it as a file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller that collects data, and (for test purpose only) save it as Excel file correctly, the piece of code is shown below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<FileContentResult> ExampleToExcel()
{
    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Example sheet");

        int index = 1;

        foreach (ExampleItem tmp in exampleItems)
        {
            worksheet.Cell(index, 1).Value = tmp.SomeData;
            index++;
        }
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        string fileName = "TheName.xlsx");

        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            var content = stream.ToArray();

            var fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(content, contentType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = fileName
            };

            return await Task.FromResult(fileContentResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get it in *.js file as

```
exampleExcelExport: function () {
    httpClient.send({
        url: "/Examples/ExampleToExcel",
        method: 'POST'
    }).done(function (response) {
        var blob = response;

        var binaryData = [];
        binaryData.push(blob);

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: "application/octet-stream" }))
        a.download = response.FileDownloadName;
        a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    });
},
```

Please note on the controller side, the length of Excel file is about 30KB, on the js side more than 50KB with bytes over value of 0x80 coded as 2 bytes.

The differences in string
*contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

and

type: "application/octet-stream"*

probably are not about, the response is much larger than I expect. Even they're the same as *"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"*, the saved Excel file is still incorrect with size more than 50KB and bytes over 0x80 coded twice.

Please let me know how can I do it correctly? How can I get from response the content as correct array of bytes and save it to file, and how can I get the name that is also in response because *response.FileDownloadName* is *undefined*?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you dont have the correct headers in your api.

You have to set `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` of your request.

A minimal working working example would be as follow.

```
 public ActionResult DownloadExcel() {
        // do the stuff to get your byte array
        var excelBytes = byte[];
        // put in some headers so the file name is availble in the response
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
        return File(excelBytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" ,"filename_you_chose.xlsx")

    }
```

And on the javascript side to extract the name of the file:

```
function(response, status, xhr){
var filename = "";
var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
    if (matches != null && matches[1]) { 
      filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
    }
}
```

}

And finaly extract the content from the response

Comment: Hello, I have found the solution. Basically, in needs to be encoded to Base64 string in C#, and decoded in js. That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Basically, it needs to be encoded to Base64 string in C#, and decoded in js.
@Admin: the topic can be closed!